# Passing a variable from Android to PHP

Tags: php, android, json, web-services

I am developing an application that uses a web service to get live data from a database, based on the user, the web service selects only that users details and sends it to the app in JSON format, the issue i am having is sending the the current users email from my app to a php file so it can get the users data

here is some of my php code

```
$email=some passed in value ;

include("includes/token.php");

        $host ="localhost";
        $user1 = "*****";
        $password = "*****";

        $connection = mysql_connect($host, $user1, $password)
            or die("Couldn't connect:".mysql_error());

            $database = "******";

            $db = mysql_select_db($database, $connection) or 
            die("Couldn't select database");

            $selectString = "SELECT studentID FROM users where email = '$email'";
            $result1 = mysql_query($selectString);
```

I know this code is fine but its getting a value from the app in to $email that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/289191/Send-and-Recive-Parameter-with-Android-To-Mysql-PH

In this full full description is given for passing a variable from andriod to php